# first time getting this error Uncaught Error in Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am working on a ToDo list and its basically done. but i am getting this error in the console that i haven't come across yet, its preventing me to create the list (to do list)

This is the error im getting:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/cpds/add
  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error             createError.js:17
  at createError (createError.js.17)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handelError (xhr.js:80)
```

Can someone please explain what this means and how to resolve this issue.
the list prints in my console but not in my browser, then prints this error afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - points that system fail to resolve IP address for given hostname (http://localhost:4000/cpds/add in your case). While it is very unlikely that you are realy could not resolve address for localhost itself most probable reason is that you requesting for closed port (:4000). 
In general this message say **Uncaught** which means that somewhere in you code when you request for "http://localhost:4000/cpds/add" form axios (it is assumtion cause you don't gave any details about your code) you have statement like

```
 axios.get(url, {  headers  })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
```

**without**

```
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

so full version is

```
 axios.get(url, {  headers  })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

So when request is fails due to any reason (probably error in url in you case) interpreter don't know how to overcome it (other words you should directly define function which would be called in case of error and pass it to catch method).
To ensure error is in url try to place http://localhost:4000/cpds/add to address bar of you browser, if it is realy unaccessable, browser should show you an error.

Answer (score -1):

This is because one of your calls returned a rejected promise/async function, or in other words: An error that occurred calling your function.

Be careful about this. You can write `yourlibrarycall.then(result => ...).catch(error => ...)` But this can quickly get a pitfall. The catch clause will be called if the library call failed, but also when the `.then` clause failed. You'd expect the failure came from the library call, but this was fine, your code might also had a problem and the value that the variable `error` returns might be totally different (or `undefined`).

Hence i prefer having:

```
yourFunction = async () => {
  let result;
  try {
     result = await yourlibrarycall // this is blocking
  }
  catch (error) {
     // error handling only of your library call
  }

  // here comes your following logic 
  ...
}
```

Using `asnyc`, your function is executed asynchronously and can now wait for the result using the keyword `await`. If the library call failed, it will enter the `catch` scope and provide you a variable with the error occurred.

This is now all the error handling and only will now only cope with the request, the following logic is then executed afterwards, getting rid of the misleading `.then(...).catch(...)`.

If you still want to use the promise approach instead of async/await be careful to handle all the errors in the catch clause explicitly, otherwise they'll bubble up and will be catched by the catch clause, as stated above.